# How do I use AnimateFloat on a TListBoxItem with StylesData in Delphi XE7 - Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I like to animate a TListBoxItem with AnimateFloat procedure. When I slide or click on the ListBoxItem I want to move it to the right/left, showing additional buttons/information, which is out of sight first.

To access the item I created in the stylebook a layoutstyle. In the StylesData of the ListBoxItem I try to call the method: StylesData['rectangle5style.AnimateFloat(''Position.X'',-150']. But that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    // To Lookup the clicked ListboxItem
    function FindItemParent(Obj: TFmxObject; ParentClass: TClass): TFmxObject;
    begin
      Result := nil;
      if Assigned(Obj.Parent) then
        if Obj.Parent.ClassType = ParentClass then
          Result := Obj.Parent
        else
          Result := FindItemParent(Obj.Parent, ParentClass);
    end;

    //Create a few Items in a ListBox
    procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Item : TListBoxItem;
      i: Integer;
    begin
      ListBox1.ItemWidth := ListBox1.Width + 150;
      for i := 0 to 24 do
        begin
          Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
          Item.Locked := false;
          Item.Parent := ListBox1;
          Item.Width  := ListBox1.Width + 150; // Hide buttons on the right
          Item.StyleLookup := 'itemstyle';
          Item.StylesData['rectanglestyle.Width'] := ListBox1.Width + 150;
          Item.StylesData['rectanglestyle.OnClick'] := TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(DoItemClick);   // set OnClick value
        end;

    end;

    procedure TForm4.DoItemClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Item : TListBoxItem;
    begin
      Item := TListBoxItem(FindItemParent(Sender as TFmxObject,TListBoxItem));
      Item.StylesData['rectanglestyle.AnimateFloat(''Position.X'',-150']; // Show buttons on the right
    end;
```

Comment: what Delphi version do you use?

Comment: actually you should read FireMonkey guides at Embaracdero docwiki site first. the code you posted above looks like some kind of nonsense. you should read how FMX works before starting to use it.

read about object ownership, components events (such as `TListBox.OnItemClick)`, read about styles and events like `OnStyleApply` and so on..

I believe you found these code snippets somewhere in web, but it is not correct way to work with styles in FMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StylesData can only be used to access properties. If you want to call a method of an object from a style then you need to call FindStyleResource passing in the StyleName of the object and returns it (if found) as a TFMXObject.

```
procedure TForm4.DoItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item : TListBoxItem;
  O: TFMXObject;
begin
  Item := TListBoxItem(FindItemParent(Sender as TFmxObject,TListBoxItem));
  O := Item.FindStyleResource('rectanglestyle');
  if Assigned(O) then
    O.AnimateFloat('Position.X',-150]; // Show buttons on the right
end;
```

BTW the normal convention for naming styles for a component is to remove the T from the class name and append the word style. For objects within a style the StyleName should be descriptive of it purpose. Your use of rectanglestyle implies you want the default style for a TRectangle.

Comment: Great! I was searching something like this.